# HTML Formatting begining and end of line

Tags: html, formatting

I have a problem with html that I have researched a lot and didn't find much help.
I want a name print at the start of line and another name at the end of line that is it. Inserting spaces is not good option as the page is designed on % basis to fit on all kinds of screens.
How to do it?
http://postimg.org/image/utm9nax6j/

Comment: Can you post something to illustrate what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below ( Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/eKh6b/2/ )

```
<html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

      <style type='text/css'>
        .left {float:left}
        .right {float:right}
        .clear {clear:both}
      </style>

    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="left clear">name1</div>
      <div class="right">name2</div>
      <div class="left clear">name3</div>
      <div class="right">name4</div>

    </body>


    </html>
```